# how to know exactly if a linux c++ library can be used in android applications?

Tags: android, android-ndk, libraries

I know that android programmers can exploit legacy c++ libraries but sometimes I read that dependencies problems could arise. Is it true? How to know in general if a library can be used before trying to compile the android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supported libraries are listed in here: [Android site - What is NDK?](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html). Other libraries exist, but may or may not be supported / changed in the future and it is not recommended to relay on them.

Comment: "The NDK can, however, can be an effective way to reuse a large corpus of existing C/C++ code." I do not think that just those few libraries on that web page can be used. So, does your answers say "you can use those libraries that use the headers of the base supported libraries"?

Comment: If you bring them with you then yes, but you cannot relay on the existence of other libraries at run-time in android other than those specified in the the link above. There are other libraries in the NDK, but they are not guaranteed to work in the future.

Comment: (Excuse me, I am not an expert) so I could bring a binary to an android device with all dependencies compiled in it so there are no futher dependencies to rely on? Are there limits to this?

Comment: Basically it is ok. And I am not expert too, but from the little experience I have it should work. Please note that not all POSIX standard is implemented in Android.